# Remove Double quotes From the payLoad Passing Odata Query Options in the Request Body

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, odata

I'm using TypeScript and I use an odata API done with Asp.Net core
I would like to pass the odata Query options in the request body
In postman it works fine
Unfortunately if i have tried to consume it through Typescript i have found that a double quote are added automatically to the querys tring
My question is why double quote are added to payload  and there is no way to forbidden that?
[image]

you will  find bellow my code with typeScript
let data='$filter=(IsLastInternalVersion eq true) and ((Entity eq 'Functional') and (Type eq 'Electric'))';

```
  this.ProductsDataSource = new DataSource({
      store: new ODataStore({
        beforeSend: function (request) {
          request.headers = {                
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
            'Accept': 'text/plain',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            "Authorization": 'bearer ' + token,
            'api-version': '1.0',
          };
          request.method = 'post';
          request.payload =data;    
        },           
        url: 'https://localhost:44388/ProductFamilies/EC225/odata/DM_Device/$query',
        version: 4,
        key: "Tag",
      

      }),        
    });
```

```
I'm try to pass query option to odata in the body :
the sended query is :$filter=(IsLastInternalVersion eq true) and (Entity eq 'Functional')
what i get :"$filter=(IsLastInternalVersion eq true) and ((Entity eq 'Functional') and (Type eq 'Electric'))"

I expect to find :$filter=(IsLastInternalVersion eq true) and ((Entity eq 'Functional') and (Type eq 'Electric')) 
whithout double quotes
```

Comment: Looks like you are using ODataStore from DevExpress. It would be better to check their documentation how to specify filter. https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Layer/DataSource/Methods/#filter

Comment: i'm here not about to create a filter i'm about of passing OData query options in request body to resolve the problem of url is quite long which potentially exceeding the maximum length that many hosting environments (including IIS) impose

Comment: I will try to ask devextreme about that Thank you so much